# Using PHP to search all mysql tables and format in table

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm currently trying to search through all tables in a database for a specific string, and then format it with PureCSS tables.

I'm using this code to search all tables from another post:

```
$database = 'Selekt';
$criteria = '*username'

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname={$database};charset=utf8", 'root', '');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$tables = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLES");
while (($table = $tables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) !== false)
{
$fields = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ?");
$fields->execute(array ($database, $table[0]));

$ors = array ();
while (($field = $fields->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) !== false)
{
    $ors[] = str_replace("`", "``", $field[0]) . " LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(:search, '\\\\', '\\\\\\\\'), '%', '\\%'), '_', '\\_'), '*', '%'), '?', '_')";
}

$request = 'SELECT * FROM ';
$request .= str_replace("`", "``", $table[0]);
$request .= ' WHERE ';
$request .= implode(' OR ', $ors);
$rows = $dbh->prepare($request);

$rows->execute(array ('search' => $criteria));

$count = $rows->rowCount();
if ($count == 0)
{
    continue;
}

if($count > 1){
$timesif = "times";
} else {
$timesif = "time";
}

$str = '"'.$criteria.'" was found '.$count.' '.$timesif.' in "'.$table[0].'"';
echo str_repeat('-', strlen($str)), PHP_EOL;
echo $str, PHP_EOL;
echo str_repeat('-', strlen($str)), PHP_EOL;
echo "<br>";

$counter = 1;
while (($row = $rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false)
{
    $col = 0;
    $title = "Row #{$counter}:";
    echo $title;
    foreach ($row as $column => $value)
    {
        echo
        (($col++ > 0) ? str_repeat(' ', strlen($title) + 1) : ' '),
        $column, ': ',
        trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', str_replace(array ("\r", "\t", "\n"), array ("", "", " "), $value))),
        PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $counter++;
}
}
```

What this script does is simply search through all my tables in the set databases by the string variable $database.
But the response will end up something like this:

```
--------------------------------- "*username" was found 1 time in "db_user" ---------------------------------   

Row #1:   
userid: 42   
username: Naido  
Password: iu1j2jnrjnfj12  
salt: 1fnj2nj  
admin: no  
active: yes
```

How could i format that, into something like this:

```
<table class="pure-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>userid</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>password</th>
        <th>salt</th>
        <th>admin</th>
        <th>active</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>Naido</td>
        <td>iu1j2jnrjnfj12</td>
        <td>1fnj2nf</td>
        <td>no</td>
        <td>yes</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Its a simple PureCSS table, i'm not sure how to format this, any suggestions?
And if i wanted to export the output to CSV, how could i do that?

Comment: i do not think it is good practice to search whole database for strings.. what about that password or salt.. or other private things stored in there.. for generating csv i like to use fputcsv() docs here-> [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: @Jimmmy those were random things i put for the explaination of the question

Comment: @Jimmmy more realistic use is searching through posts, comments, etc.

Comment: then why not use something like SELECT * FROM comments as c WHERE c.text LIKE %<searched_phrase>% ?

Comment: @Jimmmy Because, like i said, i got the script from another post.